# Access 2013: Distribute FE or leave on shared network drive for split DB

Tags: ms-access

Just wondering what the best practice is for the front-end portion of a split database. The company has a shared drive that everyone has access to and is where the back-end actually is. Just wondering if it is better practice to distribute a copy of the FE to everyone or if I should just point them in the direction of the FE on the shared drive. The latter seems easier to maintain although I know there is software to help manage FE distribution.

Comment: [In multi-user situations, each user receives a local copy of the application file, linked to the tables in the single remote data file.](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-01.html) ("Application file" is the FE.)

Comment: Created 1994 and updated 2010. I have read documents that suggest distributing a front end to every user, but none say why. A lot of them are old articles to so is it that even still best practice? What would the benefit be over having everyone access a single FE file on a shared server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so is it that [distributing a separate copy of the front-end to each user] even still best practice?

Yes, even in 2016 it is not only the best practice, it is **absolutely required** for reliable operation with multiple concurrent users.

> What would the benefit be over having everyone access a single FE file on a shared server?

When multiple concurrent users open the same copy of a front-end database file Access will get confused about the state of open objects (primarily Forms and their associated Recordsets). The data from the back-end can *appear* to be corrupted, although it may not actually be corrupted at the table level.

When multiple concurrent users each have their own local copy of the front-end file Access does not get confused and the application works correctly. That is the benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit is that all users always have a fresh and updated copy and - in case of a failure - they can just run the shortcut again to have a fresh copy.

This even works in a Citrix environment:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](http://rdsrc.us/Ly9x1v)