# Access as multi-user database

Tags: ms-access, sharing, multi-user

We have used an Access database located in shared network drive for a few years. There are about six simultaneous users, not all of them active all the time.

What is best practice to use Access as work group database?
We haven't faced any problems other than when opening database it gives this error:

> [Microsoft Access                                                             ×
>
> **<kbd>?</kbd>** You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time.
>
>     If you proceed to make changes, you may not be able to see them later.
>
>                                     <kbd>OK</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byKU0.jpg)

It can be bypassed by clicking the error note like 20 times! Then it works just fine.
It's quite a simple database based on few forms which users will use.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35189702/2144390

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access 2013: Distribute FE or leave on shared network drive for split DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189702/access-2013-distribute-fe-or-leave-on-shared-network-drive-for-split-db)

Comment: If your database is not split, then should do that.

Answer (score 1):

> It can be bypassed by clicking the error note like 20 times!

That's Access trying to perform 'Name Autocorrect'.  You should have the database settings "Track name AutoCorrect info" and "Perform name AutoCorrect" both turned off.

Also, Access was originally designed as a multi-user database, with the form and report designs stored as records in the database. It no longer uses that storage design, and files that contain forms and reports should not be opened in shared mode (another database option that should be set/reset).

The original decision to move away from shared-mode form and report design was influenced by a file-corruption bug in SMB on NT5.0, but having made that decision MS never felt the need to re-implement the original functionality.

Answer (score 0):

use a split Access db into a Front End file and Back End file.  all users have their own individual FE file....and all those FE files link to the single common BE file.  This is the standard deployment method for multiple user and works fine.  we have Access apps with 40+ users.